# Algolia Auto Complete Search in an Angular Dart Component

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, algolia, dart-js-interop

I am trying to implement the Algolia Search Autocomplete function into an Angular Dart Project.

I am able to get it to work if I put the input search box on the Index page, but if I put the search box in a component, it does not work.

Please see the attached GitHub Project outlining my issues.

[Link to GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jbhsoftware/algolia_test.git)

When it loads, you'll see two search boxes labeled appropriately.

One of them works, the other does not.

What do I need to do to get that search box working in a component?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Algolia but I'm guessing this is a timing issue.

The script to initialize the search box is run before the angular app has started and so Algolia can't find the input.

There is a couple of things you could do:

- Not run the JS script, or initialization until the component is
  fully loaded. Using ngOnInit and package:js to call the initializing
  script
- Or reparent the input box in the component itself. Load it
  in the main page with the JS script, and then in the component using
  dart:html find the element and put it in the right place in your app.

Comment: Thank you Ted, I was able to get it working properly with your first suggestion! I have pushed the working code to GitHub if anyone needs it, but ultimately, I moved all of the initialization javascript into a js function in app.js, and then use a custom event in ngOnInit to call that js function. It works perfectly, thank you so much for your direction! Also, I upvoted your answer, but my rep isn't enough that it counts yet!